# Working of -12V buck-boost supply using LM2576

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck-boost, power-management

I want to make a -12V supply and I came across a circuit using LM2576 that match my requirement but I am not confident enough about its working.

There is a note in the datasheet **page no-16**, **Application and implementation** section saying:
Information in the following applications sections is not part of the TI component specification, and TI does not warrant its accuracy or completeness. TI’s customers are responsible for determining suitability of components for their purposes. Customers should validate and test their design implementation to confirm system functionality.

[image]

Form the functional block diagram, I understand the connection of the feedback pin, but in the buck-boost configuration in the upper image, the feedback pin is connected to the ground, and I want to know why?
Please help me understand the working of the buck-boost circuit shown in the above figure.
[image]

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf?ts=1609223000480&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: The feedback is a trick to make an otherwise positive regulator provide negative output voltage by simply changing what you regard as reference voltage. True negative regulators with feedback referenced against ground do exist if you search around. Have you tried to simulate it, or read application notes for (inverting) buck-boost converters in general to understand how they work?

Comment: The device's ground is connected to the output of the circuit (-12V). So as far as the device is concerned that is it's reference point and the feedback pin is at +12V

Comment: I couldn't find any tool to simulate this, there is no spice model I guess. They are using the adjustable type, so why would they give 12V as feedback?

Comment: D1 prevents a negative output in lower Schema